# How can i classify only-text image(petition, invoice, page of a book) and a normal image(cat,person ) as a 2 different type?

Tags: image-classification

I don't think detecting text on image does work because normal images can have text on them too(like traffic sign). Is there a way to do this? I couldn't come up with an answer.